# Сегодня начал изучать Java, первые непонятки

Tags: java

Сначала я написал самую простую программу через NetBrains, при исполнении в консоли появляется традиционное "Hello, world!". После этого я стер написанный и код и написал новый, по которому на мониторе должно появиться диалоговое окно с другим сообщением, но выполнилась старая программа, которую я давно стер (в консоли появилось "Hello,world!"). Что происходит и как с этим быть?

Comment: Перекомпилировать код.

Comment: Для начала определитесь - NetBeans или JetBrains))) 